# having 2 list how to switch between them based on the same index number of elements?

Tags: python, list, replace

How to switch between 2 list that contains items where  i need to switch between elements that have the same index number ?

example:

```
l1=["foo","bar"," "]
l2 = ["dog","cat","house "]
```

The expected output :

```
l1=["dog","cat","house"]
```

until now this what i am stuck here:

```
 if "nan" in l1:
   index_nan = l1.index("nan") # this return 2
```

how to continue from here ???

Comment: Do you just want items of `l2` in `l1`??

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems like `l1 = l2` would solve your problem.

Comment: i want to replace the item of l1 with items of l2

Comment: "i want to replace the item of l1 with items of l2" Okay. Do you know how to change an item in a list? Do you know how to decide what the replacement should be, for each of the items in `l1`? Do you know how to repeat a process? Alternately: do you know what *list slicing* is? Alternately: why not just ignore `l1` entirely and use `l2` going forward? Alternately: do you actually need to replace the items? Why? Would it work to just use `l1` as another name for the same `l2` list?

Answer (score 1):

You could just swap the variables to switch the values between 2 list

```
>> l1=["foo","bar"," "]
>> l2 = ["dog","cat","house "]
>> l1,l2 = l2,l1
```

It will switch the corresponding index values on elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l1=["foo","bar"," "]
l2 = ["dog","cat","house "]
temp = l1.copy()
l1=l2
l2=temp
```

output:

```
>>> l2
['foo', 'bar', ' ']
>>> temp
['foo', 'bar', ' ']
>>> l1
['dog', 'cat', 'house ']
```